# Ways to choose $k$ items out $n$ without overlap in the chosen sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is part of a much larger and harder problem I am solving. I feel like it's a somewhat easy combinatorics problem, but that is not my field, and I can't find a solution online.

So I have a set of $n$ distinct items. Say, $\{0,1,2,3\}$ (so $n=4$), or the positions of characters on this string: "$1111$". We know $n$ to be a power of two, and $k$ to be even.

I want to know how many ways there are to choose $k$ items from the set, without any overlap.

With $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $k=2$, if I choose $0,1,$ then I can only choose $2,3$. If I choose $0,2,$ then I can only choose $1,3.$ Etc. With those parameters, we can see there are $3$ ways to choose sets of two without overlap (aabb, abab, abba; or their complements (with a the chosen items and b the non-chosen)).

With $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $k=2$, if I choose $0,1,$ then I can choose any two out of $\{2,3,...,7\}$.

I tried to puzzle this out. I thought I had $\binom42$ ways of choosing the first two items, and then I had the remaining $\binom{4-2}{2}$ choices, but I'm not sure how to combine those facts, since $\binom{4-2}{2}$ is 1, and multiplying, subtracting, or dividing it with $\binom42$ doesn't give the right answer.

And clearly $\binom{4-2}{2}/2 = 3$ seems to be right, but I don't know how to explain the "$/2$", and if it generalizes to other values of $k$ or $n$.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: $\binom{4}{2}$ divided by 2 gives you the right answer because it cancel the subset's permutation i.e. because aabb equals bbaa etc

Comment: I do not follow what it is you are trying to count.  If you have $n$ distinct items in a set... and you ask how many ways you can choose $k$ items, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways.  You say that you want to do this "*without overlap*"... without overlap to what?  If we are only choosing once, there is nothing to overlap against.  "*If I choose $0,1$, then I can only choose $2,3$*"  Are you choosing twice?  Are you choosing $k$ items twice, so... choosing $2k$ items, $k$ of which to go to the "first" group and another $k$ to go to the "second" group?  Do you distinguish between the two groups?

Comment: If you are choosing $2k$ items, $k$ of which to go to a first group and $k$ to a second group which is distinguishable from the first group and no overlap between these... First, choose the $k$ items for the first group, then from the remaining, choose the $k$ items to go there... $\binom{n}{k}\cdot \binom{n-k}{k}$.  If you can't distinguish between the labels on the groups, then divide by two to "forget" which label was which.

Comment: Alternatively, if you dislike a "division by symmetry" argument, first pick the combined $2k$ items that will be spread among our two groups.  Among those, one of them will be the "smallest" item.  Pick which other $k-1$ items go in a group with that.  $\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k-1}{k-1}$

Comment: I know why the division by two works, but I feel like it only works for $n=4$. Would it work for $n=8$? I don't think there's symmetry there: if I choose the first two elements, I still can choose any two out of the other 6.

I am not choosing twice actually, I am trying to count the number of edges of vertices in a graph. I have vertices for all words on a n-bit string, and some rules dictate whether or not they are joined by an edge. To simplify my larger problem a lot, I am trying to count the number of edges

Comment: I think the word you need is *partition*. You want the number of ways to partition an $n$-set into $k$-sets. Powers of two, and even numbers, are irrelevant and only obscure matters.

Comment: E.g., you might want to partition $\{\,1,2,3,\dots,15\,\}$ into five sets of three. That can be done in $${15\choose3}{12\choose3}{9\choose3}{6\choose3}\div5!$$ ways.

Comment: I think it's more like I want to partition ${1,2,3,…,15}$ into two k-sized sets and one $15-2k$ sized set.

Comment: "Alternatively, if you dislike a "division by symmetry" argument, first pick the combined 2k items that will be spread among our two groups. Among those, one of them will be the "smallest" item. Pick which other k−1 items go in a group with that. (n2k)(2k−1k−1)"

Using @GerryMyerson 's notation, if I want to take a 8-sized set, and want to count the number of ways to partition it into two 2-sized sets and one 4-sized set, using that answer gives me 210 ways, but that feels wrong.

I feel I am just not explaining the problem correctly

Comment: OK, $15$ into two $3$-sets and a $9$-set: $${15\choose3}{12\choose3}\div2$$ where the $2$ is really $2$-factorial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret your problem as "how many ways can I choose $k$ things from $n$, and then choose $k$ more things from the remaining $n-k$ things?" In that case, let's think of the $n$ objects as being mapped to three different letters, $a,b,c$. Then $a$ will denote the objects in the first set, $b$ will denote the objects in the second set, and $c$ will denote objects not chosen. In the final answer, which set was chosen first/second will not matter, but we introduce this notion to make things easier to count.

This is the same as counting the number of "words" with $n$ letters that have $k$ $a$'s, $k$ $b$'s and $n-2k$ $c$'s, where the position of the letter gives the value of the entry corresponding to that letter. For example, $n=8$ and $k=2$:

$aacbccbc$ corresponds to $\{0,1\}$ for the first set, $\{4,7\}$ for the second, and the rest not chosen.

Standard combinatorics tells us that there are $${n}\choose{k, k, n-2k}$$ ways to do this. However, because you don't care which set was chosen first and which set was chosen second, the words $aacbccbc$ and $bbcaccac$ are indistinguishable to us. Since there's exactly $2$ ways for this to happen each time, you divide by $2$ again to get $$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{k, k, n-2k}$$ different ways. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, to choose $k$ elements without repetition and without regard to order from a set of size $n$, there are $ \binom{k}{n} $ ways to do this. However this considers choosing, for example, $\{0,1\}$ from the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and thereby automatically ‘not choosing’ $\{2,3\}$, as not being equivalent to choosing $\{2,3\}$ and thereby automatically ‘not choosing’ $\{0,1\}$, counting as two different ways to choose 2 items from a list of 4, since a different selection was made.

This is then why the value from $ \binom{k}{n}$ disagrees with your test examples by a factor of 2: you considered choosing a set and not choosing the same set as being equivalent. If in your application this is not appropriate, then you are free to divide by 2 to account for this difference of perspectives.

Comment: So by symmetry I can simply say $\binom{n}{k} /2$ for any $n, k$?

I can see the logic, but I am trying to "prove" or demonstrate that for cases where $k\neq n/2$ it still holds

Comment: Yes absolutely, to choose k from n is like double-counting your case when choosing a set is equivalent to not choosing it, hence the division by 2 in general. Since it holds for any n and k, then yes this includes when n is a power of 2 and k even, or when k is not equal to n/2... for any k and n.

Comment: In fact, think of how $ \binom(k,n) = \binom(n-k,n) $, either by the factorial definition, or by the fact choosing a set of size k is equivalent to not choosing a set of size n-k. Given this, you can consider uncounting every ‘double count’ of the non-chosen ones, which will be exactly half: either because we can pair them up, or because of the above equality.